# How can I access properties of a generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, properties

I have the following code, where the data variable is of generic type and I need to have access to the value of the properties of that object.

hasOwnProperty does not work because the data is generic.

```
const data: T = getData();

for (const key in dato) {
  if (dato.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dato, key)) {
      const element = dato[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Types aside, that JavaScript is wrong. It should be `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dato, key)`.

Answer (score 0):

A generic type means literally that: the type is *generic*, i.e. you *don't know what it is*. If you don't know what it is, then you don't know what properties it has, or if it even has any properties *at all*.

Since you don't know which properties the type has, or even if it has any properties at all, it would obviously not be type-safe to access them. E.g. `{}` would be a perfectly valid value for `data`.

If you want to access a property, then you need to *bound* the generic type to some type that has that property.

Comment: Right, that's the nature of generics, I must think of another way to solve the problem.